# Freeing Static Structures in C Library

Tags: c, matlab, static, structure, mex

A project I am working on involves a flight vehicle with GNC code written in a C library (.out). We must call this C code from LabVIEW (the primary avionics software) in the form of a .out library, and the nature of the software requires static pointers to store data between successive calls to the function. We call the GNC executive function at regular intervals throughout a flight. I'm now trying to call this function using a Matlab MEX wrapper in a DLL on Windows, and this has uncovered some memory management issues.

I am declaring the structures at the beginning of the function like this:

```
static Nav_str *Nav_IN_OUT_ptr;
static  hguid_ref *Guid_IN_OUT_ptr;
static  HopControl *Control_IN_OUT_ptr;

Nav_IN_OUT_ptr = (Nav_str *)malloc(sizeof(Nav_str));
Guid_IN_OUT_ptr = (hguid_ref *)malloc(sizeof(hguid_ref));
Control_IN_OUT_ptr = (HopControl *)malloc(sizeof(HopControl));
```

This happens during every run of the function. However, after this function is called iteratively several times, it always crashes with a memory segmentation fault after it tries to exit. My understanding was that this memory was supposed to clean itself up, is that incorrect?

In order to clean it up manually, I added these lines to the end, to be called only on a clean-up iteration:

```
free(Nav_IN_OUT_ptr);
free(Guid_IN_OUT_ptr);
free(Control_IN_OUT_ptr);
```

Is this the correct way to free this memory? Can I free this memory? Might there be another reason for the segmentation error other than C not giving up the memory properly after the last call, or Matlab not properly managing its memory? I've searched all over for someone with a similar problem (even contacting Mathworks) without much luck, so any comments or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does have a memory leak - it is allocating that memory each time the function is called.  Even your current method still has the memory leak - if you only call `free()` once, in the final iteration, then you have only freed the most recent allocation.

However, a memory leak will not generally cause a segmentation fault (unless your memory leak exhausts all available memory, causing subsequent `malloc()` calls to return `NULL`).

If you wish to have static structures that are only allocated once and re-used, you do not need to use `malloc()` at all - you can simply change your declarations to:

```
static Nav_str Nav_IN_OUT;
static hguid_ref Guid_IN_OUT;
static HopControl Control_IN_OUT;
```

... and use `Nav_IN_OUT.field` instead of `Nav_IN_OUT_ptr->field`, and `&Nav_IN_OUT` in place of `Nav_IN_OUT_ptr` (if you are directly passing the pointer value to other functions).

Comment: With this you bring up some new issues I hadn't yet thought of, thanks! I was originally declaring the pointers this way, but still had the same problem (or maybe a different problem with similar results?), so I switched to using malloc() in hopes that I could then free the memory and remove the segmentation fault. To do what you say above, should I still call malloc() once the first time I call the function, or should I not use malloc() at all?

Comment: @tsteiner: There would be no need to call `malloc()` at all, with the above declarations the objects themselves are statically allocated.

Comment: I made a dummy function that doesn't manipulate the data at all and called that through my mex wrapper function, and still got the same error. This means my errors have apparently been called by Matlab's memory management all along. Your response above is what our actual flight code uses (and what runs correctly). What I posted above was a different idea. So thanks for your response, and what is given above does appear to run as desired.

Answer (score 3):

Failing to free memory is not going to cause a segmentation fault. It's probably likely your problem lies somewhere else. The two likely conditions are:

1. Overflowing a buffer
2. Using a pointer to memory that has previously been free'd.
3. Using a bad pointer value, somehow set incorrectly.
4. Trying to free a pointer not returned by malloc'd (or already free'd)

---

> My understanding was that this memory
>   was supposed to clean itself up, is
>   that incorrect?

Yes, you need to call `free()` to release the memory back to the heap. I would also suggest that you set the pointer value to `null` after the free, this may help you catch condition 2, from above.

---

```
Nav_IN_OUT_ptr = (Nav_str *)malloc(sizeof(Nav_str));
```

This code statement is questionable. What is `Nav_str` type? Are you sure you don't mean to use `strlen(Nav_str)+1`?

---

I also need to ask what is the purpose for making your pointers static? Static function variables are basically globals, and only to be used in rare cases.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. My understanding of how LabVIEW's embedded systems can call code written in C is that it must be compiled into a .out library. We are running in a real-time environment, so we cannot simply run one function continuously to store the data (unfortunately). We have limited bandwidth available and need to store hundreds of values during operation, which are all kept in these three structures: Nav_str, hguid_ref, and HopControl (written by different people, hence the naming). We store constants and run-time calibration data here. Hopefully that helps to clarify?

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding was that this memory was supposed to clean itself up, is that incorrect?

Sorry, but you were incorrect. :) Memory allocated with `malloc()` will persist until you manually remove it with `free()`. (You *did* get this right in the end. Hooray. :)

> Is this the correct way to free this memory? Can I free this memory?

That *is* the correct way to free the memory, but it might not be in the correct *place*. In general, try to write your `free()` calls the same time you write your `malloc()` calls.

Maybe you allocate at the start of a function and then free at the end of the function. (In that case, on-stack memory use might be better, if the memory is only ever used by functions called by the original function.)

Maybe you have a `foo_init()` function that calls `malloc()` and creates associated contexts from an API, then you pass that context into other routines that operate on that data, and then you need to place the `free()` calls into a `foo_destroy()` or `foo_free()` or similar routine. All your callers then need to balance the `foo_init()` and `foo_free()` calls. This would be especially appropriate if you can't just write the `foo_init()` and `foo_destroy()` calls in one function; say, your objects might need to be removed at some random point in a larger event loop.

And maybe the data should just be allocated once and live forever. That would be correct for some application designs, and it's tough to tell just from the variable names whether or not these blocks of data should live forever.

> Might there be another reason for the segmentation error other than C not giving
>   up the memory properly after the last call, or Matlab not properly managing its memory?

There sure could be; perhaps this memory is being returned too soon, perhaps some pointer is being `free()`ed two or more times, or you're overwriting your buffers (that `malloc(sizeof(Nav_str))` call is a little worrying; it is probably just allocating *four* or *eight* bytes, based on the pointer size on your platform; and before you replace it with `strlen()`, note that `strlen()` won't leave space for a `NUL` byte at the end of the string; `malloc(len+1);` is the usual pattern for allocating memory for a string, and I get concerned any time I *don't* see that `+1` in the call.)

Some time with `valgrind` would doubtless help find memory errors, and maybe some time with Electric Fence could help. `valgrind` is definitely newer, and can definitely handle 'large' programs better (since electric fence will allocate a new page for every `malloc()`, it can be expensive).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, this is very helpful. I don't have any previous experience with malloc(), sizeof(), or free(). If I'm understanding you correctly, I need to make sure that I call malloc() and free() the exact same number of times. I'm currently calling malloc() every time the function is called, and free only once when I'm done with everything. If I call malloc() only once, how do I hold on to that memory location between function calls, so I can access the data on each time step (1 time step = 1 call to the function in this case)?

Comment: @tsteiner, if your data should live the lifetime of the program, then you don't necessarily need to `free()` it. After reading through your comments, I think @caf's suggestion might be closest to correct. Can you post the entire function? It might be  unrelated to these data structures.

Comment: The data does need to live the lifetime of the program. Unfortunately I'm not able to post the function, but @caf's suggestion does work correctly. Thanks again for taking the time to help me out.